# Coloring will not work on tailwindCSS, all other tailwind queries work, however bg-colors do not

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Coloring of any type especially background colors wont work, I think it may be an issue regarding the certain styles, or an issue with tailwind.config file

I think the issue may be installation related, I try to follow the install steps that tailwind docs provide but keep falling short at:

Specified input file ./src/input.css does not exist.

I do infact have input.css there with the correct tailwind directives, so I'm thinking maybe the issue may be the path? I have all files under a folder called rating_app which is located in src, this is driving me bananas and I appreciate all help

```
 HTML/CSS
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body >
        
    <div class="flex justify-center items-center h-screen  ">
        <div class=" box-content h-60 w-64 p-4 border-4 items-center rounded-lg bg-slate-800  ">
            <div class="mb-4  "> How did we do?</div>  
            <div class="text-md mb-8">Please let us know how we did with your support request. All feedback is appreciated to help us improve our offering!</div> 
            <form class="flex space-x-6 justify-center tracking-wide ">
            <div id="one">1</div>  
            <div id="two">2</div> 
            <div id="three">3</div> 
            <div id="four">4</div> 
            <div id="five">5</div>
            </form>
            <div class="mt-5 flex items-center justify-center">
            <button  type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>

TAILWIND_CONFIG, nothing is configured specifically as I'm taking a coding challenge, however using tailwinds before with the regular npm install worked fine so I'm not sure where the problem lies. 



 module.exports = {
      content: [],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
```

Please ignore this part as stack exchange keeps saying this is mostly code, heck this dumb rule.

Comment: `"./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","./public/index.html"` add this is content

Comment: thanks for helping out! @charchit I entered it as: module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","./public/index.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Unfortunately it did not work :/

Comment: Can you provide the folder structure of your project as well as the content of your config-file ?

Comment: You need to include the path to the files where tailwind classes are used in content. See the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration)